# Proof that $3^n > 2^n$ for all natural numbers greater than or equal to $1$

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

*Claim*: $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \geq 1,\,3^n > 2^n$

*Proof*: Proceed by induction on $n$.

*Base Case (n=1)*: $3^1 > 2^1$ true.

*Inductive Hypothesis*: Assume for $n=k\geq 1$ that $3^k > 2^k$

*Inductive Step*:

$\begin{align}
3^{k+1} > 2^{k+1} \\
3 \cdot 3^k > 2 \cdot 2^k
\end{align}$

By the inductive hypothesis we know that $3^k > 2^k$. After this I'm stuck as to how to prove the seemingly obvious $3 \cdot 3^k > 2 \cdot 2^k$ - do I even need to prove it? The only thing I can think of is splitting the multiplication into addition, but then what?

Comment: Use the inductive hypothesis?

Comment: $3^{k+1}=3\cdot 3^k>3\cdot 2^k>2\cdot 2^k=2^{k+1}$ (using that all involved are $>0$)

Comment: @SahibaArora I'm already using it.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen do you mind elaborating on this more? I'm having trouble following those inequalities

Comment: If $a>b$ and $c>0$ then $ac>bc$.

Comment: Alternatively, $3^{k+1}=3^k+3^k+3^k>2^k+2^k+2^k>2^k+2^k=2^{k+1}$

Comment: $3/2>1$, then $(3/2)^n>1$(why?).$\Rightarrow 3^n>2^n$. This process holds for any real number greater than $1$.

Comment: $3 > 2$ so of course $3^n > 2^n$. Right...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the inductive step you start with what you are attempting to prove.  You should say assume $3^k \gt 2^k$.  Then $3^{k+1}=3 \cdot 3^k \gt 3 \cdot 2^k \gt 2 \cdot 2^k=2^{k+1}$  In each of the $\gt$ signs we replace a term on the left with a smaller term on the right.

Comment: Where was the inductive hypothesis used here?

Comment: It was use in the first inequality where we replace $3^k$ by $2^k$